# MSAL for pythonのget_accounts()メソッドでusernameだけが空になって返ってくる

Tags: python, azure

MSAL for pythonを使っています。
AADB2Cでテナントを作成し、ユーザーとしてhogeを追加、アプリの登録を済ませてあります。

```
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET, token_cache=cache)
```

と定義して、

```
app1.get_authorization_request_url([], state=None, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_PATH)
```

で得られたURLからログイン画面に遷移、そこからhogeさんにログインしてもらってアプリに帰ってきます。
URLのqueryからcodeを受け取り、そのcodeでトークンを得、キャッシュをシリアライズしました。

```
token = app.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(code=code['code'], scopes=SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_PATH)
cache = cache.serialize()
```

ここから質問なのですが…

- 以下のようにacquire_token_silentを使用したのですが、何も返ってきませんがこれは正常な動作でしょうか？

```
result = app1.acquire_token_silent(scopes=SCOPE, account=None)
print(result)
  None
```

- その後さらに、cacheをデシリアライズしたものを使用してConfidentialClientApplicationをインスタンス化し、get_accounts()を使用しましたが、home_account_idやlocal_account_idなどはuser:taroの情報が正しく表示されますが、usernameのみ空が返ってきてしまいます。何が原因で、どうすればtaroのusernameが返ってくるのでしょうか？

```
cca = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET, token_cache=acache)
accounts = cca.get_accounts()
print(accounts[0])

{
  "home_account_id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx（hogeさんとして登録されてるい値）", 
  "environment": "xxxxxx.b2clogin.com",
  "username": "",
  "authority_type": "MSSTS",
  "local_account_id": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx（hogeさんとして登録されている値）",
  "realm": "xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: cache empty and refresh error into one return value, None. (キャッシュが emptyで refreshエラーなら `None`が返る, ようですね。https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#msal.PublicClientApplication.acquire_token_silent

Comment: ありがとうございます。キャッシュやエラーを中心に、もう少し調べてみたいと思います。